# Can anyone reject suggested edits?

Tags: discussion

After reading a post on meta.so, I noticed the https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/XXX page. I'm guessing that it's part of the so-called moderator tools a user receives as moderator or reaching 10k reputation.

It didn't take long to find the [latest suggestion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/668) and reject it. *Note: I didn't maliciously reject it - it was an irrelevant suggestion.*

Since this web page is publicly accessible, can **anyone** reject/approve edits?

Answer (score 3):

Please see: [How does peer review for edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work/76284#76284)

> - All users with the [edit privilege](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) may vote on suggested edits.

(voting includes rejecting as well as accepting)

[There is some discussion underway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84693/eeeek-i-sense-an-eeeek-question-about-missing-a-unanswered-tab) about making that page a bit more visible...